# How to Sort an array list containing a row of a sql data table by columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting, arraylist

I this is a part of my code in C#:

```
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 ArrayList readertmp = new ArrayList();
 while (reader.Read())
  {
      readertmp.Add(reader);
  }
```

reader contains several columns such as "name", "age" and ...
now I want to sort "readertmp" by one of the columns  for example "name".
anynody help me?

Comment: do you need to use an array to hold the data or can you use datatables?

Comment: Can you **show us** the SQL command you're executing??

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use a DataReader in this way. You add the same object to the ArrayList.

Comment: all I want is to sort this table by one of its columns, by any method

Comment: The best way to do sorting is to have the database do it.  Show us your SQL statement for the command.

Comment: **SHOW US YOUR SQL**!! Most likely, you just need to add an `ORDER BY (column-of-your-choice)` to it and then you have it all :....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to try a datatable you can do

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

this fills the table with your data. you can then use a dataview to sort the data.

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
dataView.Sort = " Name DESC";
```

also, as others have suggested you can just sort in your sql statement

Comment: tanx for your time,attention and help

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to order the result set in the database.

You can do this by adding the ORDER BY  statement at the very bottom of your query, you'll need to add DESC to the end of that statement if you want to sort in descending order (Ascending is the default).

Comment: tanx for your time,attention and help

Answer (score 0):

It is better to sort with DB query.
If you do not want or cannot, use this:

```
ArrayList.Sort(new myComparer())
```

You have to create your own comparer class that would make comparison on selected field, i.e. "name":

```
public class myComparer : IComparer 
{
  int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)  
  {
      string field1 = ((SqlDataReader)x)["name"];
      string field2 = ((SqlDataReader)y)["name"];
      return(String.Compare(field2, field1)); // reversed
  }
}
```

Comment: tanx for your time,attention and help